# How to add Fixtures to Spring Hibernate project

Tags: hibernate, spring

I'm trying to add fixtures / sample data to a Spring project which uses Hibernate as JPA.

I've created a fixtures.sql file (in WEB-INF/classes/fixtures.sql) containing a bunch of SQL queries that I want to execute to fill the database with sample data while I develop.
In development mode I'm using the in memory database Hypersonic InMemory, when I deploy to either Postgres or MySQL, this same data will be loaded.

How do I load this data when the application restarts / starts up? Hypersonic wipes the in-memory database every time the application restarts which means I need to go through all the steps to create sample data every time I want to test something in the front-end.

database.properties:

```
database.password=
database.url=jdbc\:hsqldb\:mem\:myproject
database.username=sa
database.driverClassName=org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver
```

persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="persistenceUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect"/>
            <!-- value="create" to build a new database on each run; value="update" to modify an existing database; value="create-drop" means the same as "create" but also drops tables when Hibernate closes; value="validate" makes no changes to the database -->
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create"/>
            <property name="hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy" value="org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.charSet" value="UTF-8"/> 
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Three potential ways:

1. Use import.sql (see http://blog.eyallupu.com/2007/05/hibernates-hbm2ddl-tool.html in the section on "create")
2. Use DBUnit (see http://onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2004/01/21/dbunit.html)
3. Write code to populate the database at @SetUp (or app startup) using by creating domain objects and saving them.

Comment: With a bit of tweaking I got the import.sql working, thanks a million!

Had to add an extra line to my persistence.xml to get it to work:
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files" value="/import.sql"/>

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the initial data called? When working within the Pylons framework (a python framework), it is called fixtures, does Spring / Hibernate use the same terminology?

Comment: I don't think Spring / Hibernate call it anything different than a fixture.   That's the usual terminology for this sort of thing.  Or rather this data is part of the test fixture.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `<jdbc:initialize-database>`, see [12.9 Initializing a DataSource](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html#d0e24249).

Comment: This is the way Spring Security recommends loading roles and permissions, but couldn't get it working earlier today. 
Thanks for the link :-)

Answer (score 2):

If you prefer a more structured approach and if you project is big enough you should take a look at https://github.com/42BV/jarb and, or http://www.liquibase.org/.
You should also consider if you need transient fresh fixtures or persistent fixtures (see xUnit Test Patterns). For spring this kind of setup may be used with the environment abstraction and bean profiles (see @Profile from 3.1)

Comment: Huge fan of liquibase, is there a nice way to integrate it with Hibernate projects?

Comment: If you have a java configured spring project, JaRB would fit perfect:

`@Bean public PopulateApplicationListener populateAppliationListener() {
return new PopulateApplicationListenerBuilder().initializer().add(new SqlDatabasePopulator(dataSource, new ClassPathResource("import.sql"))).build();}`

We also have support for loading the data asynchronously / database specific scripts / or a set of files in a directory.